# Ruby inject to create array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code

```
notebooks.inject([]) do |res, nb|
  res << nb.guid if Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name)
end
```

The first `nb` has matches the condition and `res` looks like this

```
["xxx1234"]
```

The second `nb` does not match the condition which then **delete/clears** `res`

```
nil
```

From my understanding, the first value should remain in the array.

I'm also assigning this to a variable and want it to be a one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inject` works a little differently from how you're imagining.  It simply returns the last return value of the loop as it loops through each item. An easy way to fix this is:

```
notebooks.inject([]) do |res, nb|
  res << nb.guid if Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name)
  res # Returns the res array
end
```

That said, you should probably use `select` for your use case as you seem to be just filtering down which set of notebooks you want..  That is:

```
notebooks.select{|nb| Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name)}.map(&:guid)
```

Generally, I've used `inject` when I need to run math on a group of items.  e.g.

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(0) {|res, x| x * 2 + res}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to two loops, but cleaner and still one-liner:

```
notebooks.select { |nb| Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name) }.map(&:guid)
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking. This helps readability too, because you're splitting the problem into 2 distinct steps. I'd break it into at least 2 lines though.

Answer (score 0):

The accumulator must be returned on each loop iteration:

```
notebooks.inject([]) do |res, nb|
  Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name) ? res << nb.guid : res
end
```

Actually, on each subsequent loop iteration, the accumulator passed to `res` block parameter is *exactly what was returned from the previous iteration*.

In your example, on the second iteration `if` returns `false` and

```
res << nb.guid if Recipe::NOTEBOOKS.include?(nb.name)
```

line is not executed at all. That said, after the second iteration, the accumulator takes a brand new value, that is apparently `nil`.